# Online Service to validate how complete an english statement is?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a Google, or any other online service that I can pass it an english statement that checks whether the statement is complete or not.

For example, a sentence as: "Hello Sarah, How"

The service should response by saying incomplete statement. In other words, the sentence would be meaningful if you say: "Hello Sarah, How are you?" or "Hello Sarah, How is studying?"

Thank you in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.phraseup.com/completions?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hello%20sarah,%20how%20%2a&commit=Complete

I am not sure if they provide any API or if they allow page scrapping as per terms of use.